# Geth: err="chain not synced beyond EIP-155 replay-protection fork block"

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I think that my ethereum-client is fully synced (eth.syncing):

```json
{
  currentBlock: 14120968,
  healedBytecodeBytes: 142718,
  healedBytecodes: 17,
  healedTrienodeBytes: 1636523253,
  healedTrienodes: 3149949,
  healingBytecode: 0,
  healingTrienodes: 3260,
  highestBlock: 14121047,
  startingBlock: 14118913,
  syncedAccountBytes: 40139704689,
  syncedAccounts: 192419805,
  syncedBytecodeBytes: 2998839139,
  syncedBytecodes: 495548,
  syncedStorage: 643088787,
  syncedStorageBytes: 137839852092
}
```

Furthermore, I have used the following command to start geth:

```bash
geth --http --http.corsdomain localhost --ws --ws.addr "192.168.1.196" --ws.origins "*" --rpc.allow-unprotected-txs --rpc.gascap=0 --rpc.txfeecap=0
```

Nonetheless, on using chainlink with geth, I get the following error on both the ethereum-client and my chainlink node:

```
err="chain not synced beyond EIP-155 replay-protection fork block"
```

`snap-sync` is most likely used as I have not specified anything else.
I would be delighted about some ideas for fixing this issue.

Comment: If eth.syncing returns that data then it hasn't finished syncing.

Comment: So the issue might be that my hard drive cannot keep up...

Comment: Until eth.blockNumber in the geth returns a block number close to the latest in etherscan it will not have fully synced.